# Low memory disc space + startVideoCapture method returns true

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a question related to disc space of the iOS device.

I have a iPod touch device with no disc space in it and when I try to capture a video via camera app,it throws an alert message saying "No enough storage".

But in my app if I try to do video recoding using startVideoCapture method of `UIImagePickerController` then video record doesn't happens. When I execute startVideoCapture method, the app prints a console message "/var/mobile/Media/PhotoData/takingvideo activity indicator already cleared".

I am not sure what this mean. When I stop video recording via stopVideoCapture of `UIImagePickerController`, then it prints a console message "`UIImagePickerController`: ignoring request to stop video capture; camera is not currently capturing video."

I am not sure why video capture is not happening or startVideoCapture is not returning NO when there is no disc space. I am trying this in iPod touch 4th gen device having OS ver 5.1. Any one have what might be the issue?

Thanks,
Naveen

Comment: Anyone have inputs on this please? I am waiting

Comment: Thanks Pere for proper alignment of text in my question. I will take care of this in future.

Comment: did you ever figure out what was wrong?  I'm having the same issue.